# AMDGPU-Pro cause flickering with MSI R9 390

Tags: amd-graphics, gpu-driver, msi

I have installed the amdgpu-pro driver on ubuntu 16.04. After that i have very flickering desktop and after a couple of time (like 10 min) it freeze for a long time. 
Where can i get logs for that kind of problem, and is there any solution?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the driver settings? If you open "System Settings" and go to "Additional Drivers" tab, there is a list of all AVALIBLE drivers for your system. The driver your using is probably unsupported.

Comment: yes but the old "fglrx" isnt in the packetes anymore so the amdgpu-pro is the newes one. And the radeon si driver crashes. If i use the radeon driver i have to set "radeon.dpm=0" otherwise it crash. This meas to that games running realy worse! :(